# Group of order 42 cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

As a follow-up from this question:
[Groups of order 42](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1527928/groups-of-order-42/1527941#1527941)

I realize that this would probably mean that $G$ is cyclic, could someone walk me through the logic behind this?

Answer (score 2):

The question is:

> If $G$ is a group of order $42$ and we have a surjective homomorphism $\varphi: G \to C_{21}$, must $G$ be cyclic?

We have [seen](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1527941/589) that $\ker\varphi\subseteq Z(G)$. This implies that $G/Z(G)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $C_{21}$ and so is cyclic.
It is well known that

> If $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, then $G$ is abelian.

Therefore, $G$ is abelian. Since $42=2\cdot3\cdot7$ is a product of distinct primes, $G$ must be cyclic.

(Indeed, there are elements $g_p \in G$ of order $p$ for $p=2,3,7$. Then $g_2g_3$ has order $6$ and $g_2g_3g_7$ has order $42$.)

Comment: And [I thought](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/999247/if-g-zg-is-cyclic-then-g-is-abelian-what-is-the-point) that well-known fact was rather silly...

Comment: Is it always so that if product of the order of a abelian group is composed of distinct primes then it must ne cyclic?

Comment: @KprimeX, yes, it is. The proof is as in the last sentence.

Comment: Is there any other way to show that it is abelian?

Comment: I also presume that C21 is <21> right?

Comment: @user92821, I know no other way to prove that $G$ is abelian. $C_{21}$ is the cyclic group of order $21$.